# Операционная система для iot устройства

Tags: linux, grub, iot

Konstantin Zb.:
Не знаю как написать гуглу чтобы он показал то что мне надо. В общем у меня идея сотворить устройство на базе вот такой коробочки: https://sl.aliexpress.ru/p?key=DtNZwd0

И мне надо чтобы оно работало как, например, какой-то роутер, т.е. втыкаешь его в сеть, он получает адрес по dhcp и публикует свой web-интерфейс. Через него будет реализована возможность менять сетевые настройки устройства и настраивать работающее на устройстве приложение. Вдобавок нужна кнорка ресет чтобы сбросить состояние устройства "до заводских"

Я не пойму как это реализовать) Операционка должна быть каким-то линуксом, чтобы поддерживал установку jdk и умел работать с жесткими дисками.

Приложение на java готово, проблема в понимании как сделать эту низкоуровневую инициализацию:

- при включении получение ip, запуск приложения.
- реализация кнопки для сброса всего до заводских

Есть какие-то мысли на этот счет, или может кто-то сталкивался с подобными задачами?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: мутный какой-то аппарат, даже на сайте производителя нет про мать никаких данных, возьмите лучше Raspberry Pi4, океан информации и по железу и по софту и по IoT

Comment: Там ничего нет, планирую использовать обычный ibm pc. Я вот уже и думаю, может пора изучать распберри. Нашел по своему вопросу что-то подобное: https://www.google.com/amp/s/habr.com/ru/amp/post/551972/. Но слишком много непонятного. Думал может существует какой-то абстрактный линукс для встроенных систем, который позволяет реализовать это на ibm pc

Comment: 1) Насколько я понимаю, любой линукс может получать ip по dhcp и запускать приложения, прописанные в стартовом файле; 2) вам важна именно аппаратная кнопка?

Comment: если на обычную x86,x64 плату, то лучше наверное делать на debian, потому что там минимум лишнего, а статья это под конкретную плату, для raspberry например совсем по другому, там нет u-boot, для nvidia плат тоже по другому

Comment: опять же если вам понадобится линукс с ядром реального времени, то для debian preempt-rt ядро можно установить прямо из репозитария

Comment: Это корпус для обычного ПК. Тут IOT не пахнет)